# GUI - Digits in a textbox loop not working

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

```
Public Class Form1
Public digits As String = "0123456789"
Public userInput As String
Public digitCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    userInput = Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each i As Char In userInput
        If digits.Contains(i) Then digitCount += 1
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub


Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(sender As Object, e As MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected

End Sub
```

End Class

What should my loop be since this one isn't working and what is the syntax for entering in my digitCount in my maskedtextbox1

Comment: get rid of the spaces in `digits` or you will be writing code to skip them if the textbox also has spaces.  otherwise, how does the loop you have not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks plutonix :)  now that leaves me with how to get the value to show up in the textbox!

Comment: `TextBox2.Text = digitCount.ToString` should work

Comment: Hmm I am still getting an error in my loop, the app crashes when ever I launch.

Comment: updated accordingly as of now

Answer (score 0):

Replace your loop with the following simple statement:

```
digitCount = userInput.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))
```

N.B. Requires reference to System.Linq, which is there by default.